# Quartz net Scheduler -Schedule Job

Tags: quartz.net

I have what should be a simple task.  I create a new job,  make if  durable and add add using the IScheduler.AddJob method.  The job is registered but for the life of me I can not figure how to assign triggers to it.

Comment: Did you have a look at the API-Documentation? http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/topic928.html

Comment: I have indeed spend quite a bit of time looking over the API.  I did get it working.  The wording in the Schedule Job Method is a bit odd in my opinion an the interface does not clearly convey its intent.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the [tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/lesson_3.html):

```
// construct a scheduler factory
ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

// get a scheduler
IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
sched.Start();

// construct job info
JobDetail jobDetail = new JobDetail("myJob", null, typeof(DumbJob));
// fire every hour
Trigger trigger = TriggerUtils.MakeHourlyTrigger();
// start on the next even hour
trigger.StartTime = TriggerUtils.GetEvenHourDate(DateTime.UtcNow);  
trigger.Name = "myTrigger";
sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
```

Comment: My issue was not how to create a job or how to schedule a job it was in how to add one or more triggers to an existing job.  The trick was in the use of the ScheduleJob(trigger) overload with the existing job detail attached to the trigger.  The method in your example fails because it attempts to create a duplicate the job when it schedules it.